# How to format Ruby array to be used as data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm trying to display a chart titled "Purchases over Time" using Highcharts in my Rails 3.1 app.

In my function I am returning an array made up of the `created_at` date (in date format) and value of purchase (in integer format). When I display the function in a view it looks like this:

```
[2012-01-065002012-01-072502012-01-08130...]
```

It translates to: [[2012-01-06, 500], [2012-01-07, 250], [2012-01-08, 130]]

In the view within the Highcharts JS code I have the following for the series:

```
    series: [{
      name: '<%= User.product_names_by_user(current_user) %>',
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
      pointStart: <%= User.from_the_first_purchase_date(current_user) %>,
      data: <%= User.purchases_over_time(current_user) %>
    }]
```

`from_the_first_purchase_date` is a function that simply returns the very first purchase date in date format.

`purchases_over_time` is the function in question (as described above).

From my understanding (or lack there of) of the Highcharts API, I can use a list of arrays with two values as the data of a chart ([Highcharts docs](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data)) whereas the first value of the array represents the x value and the second is the y value.

So, I was hoping to be able to chart the purchase value over time. In the view, my chart shows up but no data is displayed and there are no plot points visible.

I've also tried returning the array in the following format to no avail:

```
[["2012-01-06", 500], ["2012-01-07", 250], ["2012-01-08", 130]]
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the parsing suggestion, that seems to be a good solution. I ended up not returning the date and simply passing the values into Highcharts and that did the trick, but thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can convert the datetime in your controller by `Date.parse`, then use the `lazy-high-chart` gem to send the data to `HightChart` in viewer. Here is the site for `lazy-high-chart` https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify the `datetime` type for the xAxis:

```
xAxis: { type: 'datetime' }
```

And your x values should be formatted like

```
[[Date.UTC(2012,0,6),500],[Date.UTC(2012,0,7),250],[Date.UTC(2012,0,8),130]]
```

Caution, the month definition of javascript `Date.UTC` starts at 0 (0=January ... 11=December)

Comment: I did specify the xAxis as type datetime however how would I convert the first object in my array (the 2012-01-06 in date format) to the UTC format recognized by JS as you specified above? I tried putting Date.utc(value) but utc isn't a method for the Date class. I also tried Time.utc(value) and got an error `can't convert Date into Integer`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try the javascript function `Date.parse()` instead. So `["2012-01-06", 500]` would become `[Date.parse("2012-01-06"),500]`. This converts the timestring to milliseconds since 1.1.1970.